# Cannot suspend and desktop disappears after logging back

Tags: greeter, suspend, release-odin

When I suspend it wakes up immediately and shows the lock screen. When I log back in the desktop is black and I only see the mouse cursor so I can't do anything. I have to hold down the power button to shutdown and reboot.

```
EOS 6 Odin - Linux 5.11.0-25-generic
Laptop: MSI Creator-17M-A10SD
CPU: Intel i7-10750H CPU 
GC: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX® 1660 Ti Mobile
```

Comment: Same issue here. 2015 Macbook Pro 13". Happens whether I'm using external monitor or not.

Comment: Same here (Lenovo Legion 15 Ryzen 7 with Nvidia GPU), I haven't found the reason only a few bug reports from beta... looks like they didn't fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Odin on my Macbook Pro 2010 6,2 with screen locking. I read Elementary OS uses the Xorg modesetting driver by default out of the box.  I had to generate a xorg.conf, modify it to use the nouveau driver only, not i915 (removed entries).  After this I was able to lock and unlock without the black screen and cursor problem. This worked with the standard Odin wallpaper and no wallpaper specified.

I haven't gotten suspend working yet though, that has resulted in a video memory corrupted background image so far, that requires a lightdm restart or reboot.  So suspend is currently deactivated for me. I may end up trying to make just the i915 driver work, although that hasn't been easy so far.